# How to command mysql dump from Java

Tags: java, mysql

The command works perfectly when I use the Windows cmd.exe but not with my Java application.

```
String[] command = new String[]{db.getMysqlpath()+"\\mysqldump", "-u"+BuilderSession.getDbPropertice().get("username"), "-p"+BuilderSession.getDbPropertice().get("password"), s ,"|","mysql", "-u"+BuilderSession.getDbPropertice().get("username"), "-p"+BuilderSession.getDbPropertice().get("password"),  dbname };
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(Arrays.asList(command));
    processBuilder.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);        
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
    process.waitFor();
```

for example commad is  :
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqldump -uroot -p123 stroe | mysql -uroot -p123 store_1401
I got the following error:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't find table: "|"
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: The pipe symbol is a feature of the shell. Does windows's cmd even interpret it as in a linux shell?

Comment: @f1sh CMD.exe supports pipes, but if I recall correctly it doesn't run the programs in parallel.

Comment: i use windows cmd.if doesn't run the programs in parallel.What is the command and how to execute it?

Answer (score 1):

You try to invoke several commands tied together with a pipe.  This is not supported by ProcessBuilder.  It only supports invoking a single command.

The reason why it works from the command line, is because the command interpreter supports invoking several commands tied together with a pipe, by invoking each of them with something similar to ProcessBuilder and tying the output from the first together with the input to the second.

You can either choose to 1) do the same by invoking two ProcessBuilders and tie them together, or 2) invoke the command line interpreter on your command line.

Comment: thanks, What are the necessary commands to make a copy of the database?  Can you give me an example.